# PyQT object unintentionally appearing in separate window

Tags: python, pyqt6

I think I'm a bit tired and probably missing the obvious, so please, go easy on me ;)

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue, my custom QPushButton class object is being displayed in a separate window (see attached image). If I implement the button via a function and not a class, then it appears within the main window. However, since the application has several buttons (I've removed buttons to simplify the code and aid troubleshooting), to minimise the repetition of code, I want to implement a reusable class.

Clearly, the code is functioning correctly: the button is showing. My question is, how do I link my ButtonClass object to my Window object?

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtCore import *

import sys

class ButtonClass(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, set_image, set_button_geometry, set_button_resize, set_button_visible):
        super().__init__()

        # Instance variables assigned with arguments
        self.set_image = set_image
        self.set_button_geometry = set_button_geometry
        self.set_button_resize = set_button_resize
        self.set_button_visible = set_button_visible

        # Initialise instance of QPushButton
        self.button = QPushButton()

        # Declare variable, inherit QPushButton->QAbstractButton->QWidget functions
        self.button_attributes()

    def button_attributes(self):
        

        # Assign icon to QPushButton object and insert custom image
        self.button.setIcon(QIcon(self.set_image))

        # Specify button geometry
        self.button.setGeometry(self.set_button_geometry[0],
                                self.set_button_geometry[1],
                                self.set_button_geometry[2],
                                self.set_button_geometry[3])

        # Specify Icon size
        self.button.setIconSize(QSize(self.set_button_resize[0],
                                      self.set_button_resize[1]))

        # Stylesheet attributes
        self.button.setStyleSheet("border: 0px")

        # Set button visibility
        self.button.setVisible(self.set_button_visible)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Define window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Soular")

        # Define window height
        self.setFixedHeight(700)

        # Define window width
        self.setFixedWidth(400)

        # window stylesheet defines window background colour
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:'#323232'")
        self.move(10, 10)

        # initialises play_button from class 'Button_class'
        self.play_button = ButtonClass('Images/Play_standard.png', [165, 580, 70, 70], [70, 70], True)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

And this is what the output:

[Output two PyQT windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Af1.jpg)

Comment: Why are you creating *another* button *inside* a button class?

Comment: Are you referring to  the QPushButton reference 'class ButtonClass(QPushButton)' and 'self.button_attributes()'?

Comment: @IanThompson TYPO: remove `self.button = QPushButton()` and change `self.button` to `self`

Comment: Oh, of course, doh! Thank you, I appreciate the help. Do you have any idea why my button still appears in a separate window?

Comment: @IanThompson because you're not creating the widget (the button) with a parent, or, more properly, you are not adding it to a [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) as you should.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing the part that you need to tell the `QPushButton` which window it should be a part of. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324562/pyqt5-how-to-dynamically-add-widgets-to-window-without-layout), where the `QPushButton` receives the `QWidget` as an argument. In your case, you can tell `ButtonClass` that it is located within `Window`, by passing a reference to `Window` (I'll call the parameter `parent` here) to the `ButtonClass.__init__`-method and passing `parent` to the `QPushButton.__init__`-method, like this:

```
def __init__(self, parent, set_image, set_button_geometry, set_button_resize, set_button_visible):
        super().__init__(parent)
```

and by calling `ButtonClass` with a reference to `Window`, like this:

```
self.play_button = ButtonClass(self, 'Images/Play_standard.png', [165, 580, 70, 70], [70, 70], True)
```